# Express Router not showing endpoint requests

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I'm new to express and I'm trying to use express.Router() in order to route to different end points. When I follow tutorials online, I can only get text to send from the root '/' and no other endpoint. As far as I can tell my code matches well with the tutorial, so I'm not seeing where something is missing.

**express.js**

```
"use strict";
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const resources = require('../routes/resources');
const commonExpress = require('common/lib/express');

commonExpress.setup_pre(app);
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Hey Socket.io</h1>');
});

app.use('/resources', resources)
//use /routes/resources to handle endpoints
//that start with '/resources'

commonExpress.setup_post(app);

module.exports = app;
```

**resources.js**

```
"use strict";
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.url, "@", Date.now());
    next();
});

router.route('/messages').get((req, res) => {
    res.send("hi get /resources/messages")
}).post((req, res) => {
    res.send("hi post /resources/messages");
});
router.route('/messages/:userId').get((req, res) => {
    res.send("hi get /resources/messages " + req.params.userId);
}).put((req, res) => {
    res.send("hi put /resources/messages " + req.params.userId);
})

module.exports = router;
```

**commonExpress**

```
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const utils = require('./utils');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

module.exports = {
    setup_pre: app => {
        app.use(logger('dev'));
        app.use(express.json());
        app.use(cookieParser());
        app.use('/health', (req, res) => res.status(200).send());
    },
    setup_post: app => {
        app.disable('x-powered-by');
        app.use(utils.handleMezError);
        app.use(utils.handleMongoError);
        app.use(utils.handleUnknownError);
        app.use(function (req, res, next) {
            res.status(404).send();
        })
    }
};
```

These are the responses I get when I use the curl command:

```
tk@tk-desktop:~/messenger$ curl http://localhost:4000/
<h1>Hey Socket.io</h1>tk@tk-desktop:~/messenger$ curl http://localhost:4000/resources
<h1>Hey Socket.io</h1>tk@tk-desktop:~/messenger$ curl http://localhost:4000/resources/messages
<h1>Hey Socket.io</h1>tk@tk-desktop:~/messenger$ curl http://localhost:4000/resources/messages/:userId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code here:

```
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Hey Socket.io</h1>');
});
```

grabs all possibly URLs and sends a response and does not allow any of the other request handlers to see inbound requests.  Since request handlers in Express are processed in the order you register them, the only request handlers that can run before this one grabs the inbound request are the ones in `commonExpress.setup_pre(app);`.

Probably, you want to change that above route to:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Hey Socket.io</h1>');
});
```

So, it only responds to a GET request and so it only matches the exact `/` URL (see details below).

It may help you to understand a few things:

1. `app.use()` is greedy.  It will match any inbound URL that starts with the path you use.  So, if you have `app.use('/', ...)`, that will match all possible URLs since all URLs start with `/`.  As such, `app.use()` is usually used for middleware, that prepares a request/response, but doesn't actually send one and then calls `next()` to continue routing to subsequent handlers and doesn't call `res.send()` or any other method that sends a response.  Once you've sent a response and not called `next()`, all routing is done for that request.
2. Inbound requests are processed by Express in the order the request handlers are registered.  So, if you have overlapping handlers, you would generally put the more permissive handlers later and the more specific handlers earlier.  If you do the reverse which is what you have here, the more permissive handlers will grab everything and the others will never get a shot.
3. It looks like you can either change your `app.use('/', ...)` to an `app.get('/', ...)` which will only match the exact `/` URL and nothing else or you can change it to be a middleware handler that doesn't send a response and does call `next()` to continue routing.
4. It also looks like you may be using `app.use()` in other places where `app.get()` is more appropriate.  For example with `app.use('/health', ...)`, `app.use()` will match all HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, etc...), but if you are sending a response in your route handler, you typically want to be matching only one of those verbs.  If it's a request/response type of route where the browser requests content, that would be a GET and should use `app.get()`, not `app.use()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling a bunch trying to make sense of all the documentation, tutorials, and questions/responses on this site. This is SO helpful!